# Python2.7 : import multidict

Tags: python, import, mapping

I am beginner in python and using python 2.7.11 in windows 7. Downloaded multidict multidict 2.1.2‑ wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#multidict and successfully installed using pip install.

Import `multidict` showing error

```
    yield from self._items
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have removed word `from` .py and error gone. Running again showing from collections import abc (

```
ImportError: cannot import name abc
```

I also used `import abc` but no success. `_multidict_py.py` file has code on top of all `from collections import abc`.

Official multidict offering wheel for python 3.4. Most of my library and packages are running fine on py27 therefore at the moment not upgrading to 3.4

I have also installed MultiDict - Werkzeug but it also need multidict. Dict does not support unique key, while I need multiple key with various value.

Comment: well, some packages just don't support python 2 anymore. Maybe you find an appropriate (older) version of that package somewhere in `pypi`. Not sure how we could help you. I wouldn't advise to update to python 3.4 - if you ever decide to update to python 3 choose the newest version (currently 3.6).

Comment: @MSeifert: the project never supported anything other than 3.4 and newer.

Answer (score 2):

*Update*: I contacted Mr. Gohlke and the 2.7 wheel has now been removed.

---

I'm not sure why Christoph Gohlke is providing that package, as it is *not compatible with Python 2*. There never was a release that was compatible either.

From the [PyPI project page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multidict):

> - Programming Language :: Python
> - Programming Language :: Python :: 3
> - Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
> - Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5

The project requires Python 3.4 and up.

You can't just edit out the syntax errors you see. For example, `yield from` is a new Python 3 concept used in coroutines, and can't just be replaced with `yield`.

Note that the Werkzeug version is a different project, and a different implementation of the same idea. `werkzeug` works fine on Python 2.7.

Comment: Martijn, I already download  and successfully installed multidict-2.1.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl from unofficial http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#multidict site because official https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multidict has only multidict-2.1.4-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl. pip freeze showing multidict installed

Comment: @kakakhan2016: yes, but the *code in that package* won't work on 2.7. This is an error on behalf of that site. You can't run it on Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to upgrade to python 34.

Comment: @kakakhan2016: I'd go straight to Python 3.6; you get all that 3.4 has to offer plus bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martijn Pieters. I have installed latest python and all package/library including multidict are working great. Thanks for your answers.